# Find a continuous non polynomial function so that $\max|f(x)|=1$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $\max|f(x)|$ is as big as we want for $1\leq x \leq 2$

Tags: polynomials, continuity, graphing-functions

I am asked to find a continuous, not polynomial function so that $\max|f(x)|=1$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $\max|f(x)|$ is as big as we want for $1\leq x \leq 2$. I've come up with

$$
    f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
                \frac{\cos(x)}{2}, & \text{for } x=0\\
        \frac{1}{2-x}, & \text{for } 0< x\leq 2
        \end{array}\right\}
$$
Which is not very clever, what are some other examples of these kind of functions?

Comment: Your function is not defined at $x=2$. Also, such an example cannot exist as $[0,2]$ is a compact set and thus, every continuous function on it is bounded.

Comment: I really do believe, that by "max|f(x)| is as big as we want", he meant that if we want max|f(x)| to be some particular number A, we can achieve it

Comment: We can just go with piece-wise linear function, that is $1$ on $[0, 1]$, and connects point $(1, 1)$ with $(2, A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your your proposed function doesn't work, since it's not defined at $x=2$.

Here's one that works . . .

Fix $M > 0$, and let $f$ be defined by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\sin(2\pi x)&\text{if $0\le x\le 1$}\\[4pt]
M\sin(2\pi (x-1))&\text{if $1< x\le 2$}\\
\end{cases}
$$
**Notes:**

The function $f$ above is not unbounded, but it's not possible for a continuous function on $[0,2]$ to be unbounded.

However on $[0,1]$, the maximum absolute value of $f$ is $1$, and on $[1,2]$, the maximum absolute value of $f$ is $M$, which can be made arbitrarily large.

The continuity of $f$ is verified since both pieces "join" at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the piecewise definition. You could simply do
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(2+\epsilon-x)^p}$$
for some small $\epsilon>0$ and $p\geq1$. Then
$$\max_{0\leq x\leq1}f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+\epsilon)^p}<1$$
and
$$\max_{1\leq x\leq2}f(x)=\frac{1}{\epsilon^p}$$
which can be made arbitrarily large by decreasing $\epsilon$.